# Why can't I register my DebuggerVisualizer? (in VS2012)

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Following the [MSDN instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164759.aspx), I created a custom DebuggerVisualizer that looks like this:

```
[assembly: DebuggerVisualizer(
typeof(TestVisualizer.Visualizer1),
typeof(VisualizerObjectSource),
Target = typeof(MyType.SomeType),
Description = "Just a test Visualizer")]
namespace TestVisualizer
{       
    public class Visualizer1 : DialogDebuggerVisualizer
    {
        protected override void Show(IDialogVisualizerService windowService, IVisualizerObjectProvider objectProvider)
        {
            SomeType obj1 = (SomeType)objectProvider.GetObject();
            using (Form displayForm = new Form())
            {
                ... display code here ...
                windowService.ShowDialog(displayForm);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

where the target type is defined in a separate assembly like this:

```
namespace MyType
{
    [Serializable]
    public class SomeType{... class definition...}
}
```

The TestVisualizer project copies the .dll (post-build) into the required directory:

```
C:\Users\[username]\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Visualizers
```

So then I restart Visual Studio placing a breakpoint after instantiation of a SomeType object. But the visualizer is not displayed (no magnifying glass is presented).

HOWEVER, if I decorate the `SomeType` class definition like this instead:

```
namespace MyType
{
    [DebuggerVisualizer(typeof(TestVisualizer.Visualizer1))]  //this method works
    [Serializable]
    public class SomeType{... class definition...}
}
```

everything works as expected and the Magnifying Glass shows up. Likewise, if I use a `VisualizerDevelopmentHost` to display it, it works fine as well, so there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the visualizer class itself. I just don't seem to be registering it properly.

What do I need to do to get the Visualizer to work without modifying the MyType namespace?

Comment: The Target is never not a problem.  That only works if the visualizer and your code use the exact same assembly for the type.  You don't usually get that unless the assembly is registered in the GAC.

Comment: @HansPassant: That shouldn't be a problem in this case because the visualizer and the target type are both built in the same solution.

Comment: The debugger is a different process with a different probing path.

Comment: So how do I resolve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You should put MyType in a separate Assembly like in a real world scenario and try this version of the attribute:

```
[assembly: DebuggerVisualizer(
    typeof(TestVisualizer.Visualizer1),
    TargetTypeName = "MyType.SomeType, NAMEOFTHEASSEMBLYCONTAININGSOMETYPE",
    Description = "Just a test Visualizer")]
```

Don't forget to replace `NAMEOFTHEASSEMBLYCONTAININGSOMETYPE` with the name of your assembly (do not use the .dll file extension!).

Comment: Well, this wasn't the solution, but it helped me narrow it down. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I finally figured out my own problem. As it turns out, my real application was slightly different than the one I posted here. In my original application, `SomeType` was really `ISomeType` (an interface). Apparently interfaces are not supported by DebugVisualizers (at least not with the syntax I was using). When I selected an abstract base class as my target type instead, everything started to work as advertised.